# How to install Imagick extension on Windows PHP 7.0

Tags: php, windows, imagick

I need to install Imagic extension on my Apache - PHP 7.0 server. I followed very nice guide located here: https://herbmiller.me/2016/06/16/installing-imagick-php-7/. Based on "php -i" out:

```
PHP Version => 7.0.13
Compiler => MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
Architecture => x86
Thread Safety => enabled
extension_dir => D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7\ext => D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7\ext
```

I downloaded file

```
php_imagick-3.4.3rc4-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip
```

from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3rc4/. I coppied all DLL files to D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7\ext and I added

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

to my PHP.INI. When I restarted my Apache, Imagic extension was not loaded and Event viewer showed 2 same errors:

```
The description for Event ID 4 from source PHP-7.0.13 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

php[11628]
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP7\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 ("d:\Program Files (x86)\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice)
```

Please, could anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only tutorial that worked our for me:

https://tektriks.com/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-install-imagemagick-in-windows/

I am using PHP version 7.1.9 with WampServer64 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from the given tutorial:

https://herbmiller.me/2016/06/16/installing-imagick-php-7/

The file I downloaded was **ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip**

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps

Install ImageMagick to a directory of your choice

Extract the whole of the bin directory from the ImageMagick zip file to a directory of your choice. I chose C:\ImageMagick-6.9.3-7

Then set system environment variables and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html

Essentially:

1. downloading and unpacking two ZIP files
2. copy some files into the PHP installation
3. change php.ini
4. restart the web server

Answer (score -1):

This step worked perfectly for me.
First of all, download from below link.

[-Install the ImageMagick PHP extension in Windows](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html)

[image]

- Extract from php_imagick-….zip to the ext directory the
  php_imagick.dll file of your PHP installation
- Extract from ImageMagick-….zip to the root PHP directory (where
  php.exe resides) the DLL files that start with (and there are a TON):

  CORE_RL_

  IM_MOD_RL_

Add this line to your php.ini file

```
extension=imagick
```

And then to run a simple test (should output a 1):

php -r "print(class_exists('imagick'));"

---

References:

https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/224#issuecomment-367532736

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited!